# the return value of a child process

Tags: c++, exec, fork, wait, waitpid

I am new to `fork` and `exec`, and I tried the following program.

Program 1:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0){
        printf("new process");
        execv("p1",argv);
        }
    else{
        pid_t pr = wait(&status);// I am trying to get the exit value
                                //  of the sub process.
        printf("the child process exit with %d",status);
        printf("father still running\n");
    }
}
```

Program 2:

```
int main(){
    std::cout<<"I am the new thread"<<std::endl;
    sleep(1);
    std::cout<<"after 1 second"<<std::endl;
    exit(1); 
}
```

I run the first program, and the output is "the child process exit with 256". Why is the result `256` instead of `1`? If I change `exit(1)` to `exit(2)`, the result becomes `512`, why is that? It only worked if I return 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The status value you get back from the `wait` system call is not necessarily what your child process exited with.

There are a number of other pieces of information that can be returned as well, such as:

- did the process terminate normally?
- was it terminated by a signal?
- what was the signal that terminated it?
- did it dump core?

In order to extract the exit code, you use a macro:

```
WEXITSTATUS(status)
```

That, and the macros that can give you more information, should be available on the `wait` man-page, such as the one [here](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?wait%202).